# Stuck in a loop updating a value

Tags: c#

I have an application that updates values in documents, however, some of these documents have multiple entries of this value. due to this I have created a Do Something loop but this is just looping and is not replacing the values.

my code is as below:

```
do
{
    int dollarIndex = script.IndexOf("$");
    string nextTenChars = script.Substring(dollarIndex - 17, 17);
    string promptValue = CreateInput.ShowDialog(nextTenChars, "Input");
    script.Replace("$", promptValue);
}
while (script.Contains("$"));
```

Comment: Assuming its a string which is *immutable*: `script = script.Replace(...`

Comment: @AlexK, thanks Alex but this only checks the first value and does not update any of the others

Comment: `script.Replace` *returns* the new string with the replacement made - it does not change `script` in-place.  You need to store the return value overwriting the original otherwise `script` always contains a `$` so `script.Contains("$")` is always `true` so your loop will run until the heat death of the universe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable, so you need to do:

```
script = script.Replace("$", promptValue);
```

Simply doing

```
script.Replace("$", promptValue);
```

Doesn't update the value of `script`